# How to print a JTable header in two lines?

Tags: printing

Program is to print a JTabel and used function is

```
JTabel jt=new JTable();
MessageFormat headerFormat= new MessageFormat("My World Tomorrow");
MessageFormat footerFormat = new  MessageFormat("Page {0}");

jt.Print(JTabel.Format,headerFormat,footerFormat);
```

Query is: How to print the header in two lines  that is

```
My World 
Tomorrow
```

Tired following solutions:

```
new MessageFormat("My world \n Tomorrow");
new MessageFormat("My world \r\n Tomorrow");
new MessageFormat("My world" System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Tomorrow"
```

);

Nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Eruls. When posting code, indent it by 4 spaces or highlight the code and press the code formatting button when editing you question. Makes it much easier to read, and increases the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Did you try one backslash (\) ?

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
MessageFormat[] header = new MessageFormat[3];
header[0] = new MessageFormat("");
header[1] = new MessageFormat("line 1");
header[2] = new MessageFormat("line 2");

MessageFormat[] footer = new MessageFormat[2];
footer[0] = new MessageFormat("footer 1");
footer[1] = new MessageFormat("footer 2");
job.setPrintable(new MyTablePrintable(tblmunim, PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer));

if (job.printDialog())
  try {
    System.out.println("Calling PrintJob.print()");
    job.print();
    System.out.println("End PrintJob.print()");
  }
  catch (PrinterException pe) {
    System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
  }
```

originally posted here http://sandeepsharma11.blogspot.com/2010/12/java-how-to-print-table-with-multi-line.html

Comment: this is useless without the MyTablePrintable implementation, where the magic is supposed to happen.

Comment: Hi Ths it's been long time Im not working on swings but you can try this. 1) Take the code of TablePrintable and copy it in your own class "MyTablePrintable". 
2) Modify the constructor where needed.